# What can a Bard access to grant teammates Temp HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, healing, temporary-hit-points

I am playing a supportive Bard character whose schtick is that she projects barriers onto other Characters.

I am aware that they don't stack.

So far I've got Inspiring Leader (Lv4 + Cha4 to 6 allies), Heroism (Cha4, refreshes every turn), Enhance Ability - Bear (2d6), Mantle of Inspiration (5hp to 4 allies I choose).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MilesBedinger I thought mentioning Mantle of Inspiration would have made it a bit more obvious, but yes, spells only. The starting level is 4, multiclassing and additional feats (i will have to grab them at 8) is not out of the question.

Comment: If spells only with no upper bound to bard level is what you are interested in, it would be helpful to the readers to add those parameters to the question.  E.g. change the title to "What spells can a bard access that grant temp hitpoints to allies?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Sources of Temporary HP Available to Bards

You've listed so far:

- Feat: Inspiring Leader
- Bard (Glamour): Mantle of Inspiration (3rd level)
- Spell: Heroism
- Spell: Enhance Ability (Bear)

Ones you haven't listed:

- Maneuver: Rally (Feat: Martial Adept or Multiclass into Battle Master)
  *1d6 + CHA Temp HP with Feat, 1d8 + CHA or better with Multiclass*
  *Courtesy of [fabian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/22403/fabian)*
- Spell: False Life (1st Level, Req. Magical Secrets)
  *Self only, 1d4 + 4 + 5/ASL Temp HP*
- Spell: Armor of Agathys (1st Level, Req. Magical Secrets)
  *Self only, 5 + 5/ASL Temp HP*
- Consumable Magic Item: Potion of Heroism
  *10 Temp HP for 1 hour, different from the Spell of the same name*
- Minor Rare Magic Item: Bag of Beans
  *Roll a 01 on a d%, anyone can eat one of 5d4 mushrooms and then roll an even number on any die to gain 5d6 Temp HP*
- Major Rare Magic Item: Sword of Life Stealing
  *Wielder only, gain Temp HP equal to necrotic damage dealt.*

Options that have a similar effect to Temp HP

- Spell: Aid (2nd Level, Req. Magical Secrets)
  *Increases max HP by 5 + 5/ASL for 3 creatures for 8 hours*
- Spell: Heroes' Feast (6th Level, Req. Magical Secrets)
  *Increases max HP by 2d10 for 12 creatures for 24 hours*

Note: Spells that increase Max HP stack with Temp HP because they are not Temp HP.

---

From what I've seen, not many other abilities exist which allow you to give Temp HP to other people. For spells, the reason for this is that Single and Multi-target Temp HP is already covered by both the Enhance Ability and Heroism spells, while scaling Single Target Temp HP is covered by False Life. Adding additional spells for Temp HP would be redundant.

The only remaining variants of Temp HP spells which don't exist yet are Multi-target Scaling Temp HP or Single-Target Scaling Temp HP on other. However, these niches are better-covered by the Aid spell.

Comment: The options he hasn't listed that are spells with a range of self don't meet the requirement of "granting **teammates** temp HP", so it's pretty clear why they aren't listed... It's odd to call them out as not being listed when they don't meet the criteria to begin with.

Comment: @V2Blast The real question is whether or not you consider yourself to be on your own team.

Comment: ...No, that's not really much of a question here. You are pretty unambiguously not your own "teammate". Also, what does "ASL" stand for in your post? I'm guessing it is something relating to spell level?

Comment: The *Martial Adept* feat is also an option, even tough a pretty expensive one: Choosing *Rally* as maneuver one time between rests you can use a bonus action to grant an ally 1d6+CHA temp hit points.

Comment: @V2Blast Additional Spell Level

Comment: @Axoren: Ah, makes sense. I'd suggest expanding it out at least once in your answer, as it's not exactly a common abbreviation.